# Would this algorithm be able to perform transaction in dynamoDB

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

due to the need for transactions associated with NoSQL I decided to come up with a solution of my own, targeting DynamoDB. Let me know if you find a flaw, or a suggestion for improvement.

Premise. I will insert 2 objects as a transaction.

Meaning;

- The insert will rollback if both objects are not inserted successfully.
- The objects will be unavailable for read while the transaction is in progress.
- In case of a catastrophic failure, such as a power outage, a garbage collector will erase orphaned objects. (An object is considered orphaned if the transaction fails.)

Function summary: Each of the 2 object will share a unique associated transaction ID. If both insert succeeds, a transaction object will be committed to the database with the success status. If it fails, both object will be deleted.

```
//NOTE: insert means insert into the database
//      delete means delete from the database

public void InsertTwoObjects()
{
    String[] transaction_object = {'random Id', '0'};
    String[] a = {'object 1', transaction[0]};
    String[] b = {'object 2', transaction[0]};

    try{
        if !(insert(a) && insert(b))
        {   
            throw new FailedInsertException();
        }
        else
        {
            transaction_object[1]='1';
            if !(insert(transaction_object))
            {
                throw new FailedInsertException();
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(FailedInsertExpcetion e)
    {
        //rollback
        delete a;
        delete b;
        delete transaction_object;
    }
}
```

Now, we need to define a new queryDB function that will replace the traditional query function and maintain consistency with the transaction logic described above.
In another process if I try to query the a object, it will fail unless the transaction object returns a value of 1 to indicate success.

```
public string QueryObject(String[] a)
{
    String[] result = query(a);
    if (result[1]==null)
    {
         return result[0];
    }

    String[] transaction = query(result[1]);

    if (transaction[1]!='1')
    {
        throw new ItemNotFoundException();
    }
    else
    {
        return result[0];
    }
}
```

The final step is to have a periodic batch process that, similarly to a garbage collector, will scan the database for orphaned blocks older than a certain age and delete them. This is necessary if a transaction fails due to a power shortage that prevents the first function from executing its rollback.

```
public void BatchGargageCollect()
{
    while(1==1)
    {
        wait(5000);
        1. scan all objects with a transaction id appended to them
        2. query the transaction. 
        3. If valid, remove the appended transaction id from the object.
    }
}
```

Comment: AWS now supports a utility library that fulfills this need(client-side locking) by using 2 DynamoDB tables. http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/07/dynamodb-transaction-library.html

Comment: Thats transaction lib is only for JAVA. Not very useful to most of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using NoSQL with transaction supported natively by the engine? djondb on the open source side or foundation db on the commercial.

Trying to support in your code something that is not supported by the engine will become, sooner or later, into a nightmare. IMHO

Comment: Well, DynamoDB has a lot of advantages such has been fully administered by amazon.